Build and Deployment of DACPAC via Azure DevOps Pipeline without .sln (or any artifact)
I need to build, publish and deploy a .dacpac file in order the database to adhere with the changes that take place in the code.
I read several articles but all of them make the assumption of having Visual studio to generate a .sln file and from there they start building up
      - task: VSBuild@1
        displayName: 'Build Solution: bla.sln'
        inputs:
          solution: database/bla.sln
          platform: 'Any CPU'
          configuration: Release

In my case the bla.sln file is not there and I don't want to create one (if that's possible)
Tooling I'm using is: PyCharm, Azure DevOps pipeline, Azure SQL server, Azure SQL Databases
Ultimate goal: to have database as code (schemas, roles, ...) in my repo and a pipeline which when triggered will build, publish and deploy the .dacpac to some of the SQL server's databases.
Is this possible? You have an example?
After some investigation and stackoverflow discussion I realized that it's possible to have a .sqlproj file in your codebase that kinda "describes" how the database look like (tables, stored procedures and etc). If I apply some changes to the schema of these databases how these changes can be reflected in the .sqlproj file, since in the above step you only build the file?

Should I assume then that it's not possible to build and deploy a dacpac without having the .sln that relates with the corresponding project? Is it possible to build an .sln via Azure Data Studio?

Sorry, I misunderstood you. No, you don't need an .sln - MSBuild works primarily with <Project> XML files (like .csproj, but in your case, you'll need a .sqlproj - both SSDT and Azure Data Studio/Explorer/etc can produce them).

In any case I need some sort of artifact generated by one of MS products. Thanks, for the answer. Feel free to share any doc/tutorial describing how you can do that.

What is the .dacpac supposed to be based on? Do you have a prototype/template database (i.e. an SSDT projec) anywhere?

I just have an SQL server instance on azure together with some empty azure databases in there for the time being. Im planning to update them with the schema's and roles and publish profiles and etc coming the codebase

To have database as code in my repo, may I assume you have .sqlproj as the project file in your repo? If yes, you don't have to build a .sln as suggested by Dai; you can build .sqlproj instead in VSBuild pipeline task and then deploy the generated .dacpac via SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 in pipeline.

@Alvin for now I dont have one but Im planning to create one (manually if there is no other way) via Azure Data Studio. Ideally, I d like not to have any kind of artifact in my codebase but as far as I understood thats not possible. Im still puzzled with the: how the local file will get updated if it is checked in a git commit

The .sln or sqlproj files are not considered as artifact and they should be pushed as source code in your repo. Is this what you are confused about?

For the code in your local repo, you can push them into Azure Repos or any other cloud git repo provider using GIT commands. Visual Studio also has the feature to push your local repo to remote repo hosted in Azure DevOps.

@Alvin this is already helpful and thanks for that. I haven't dived in to what info an .sqlproj file contains, but my assumption (which is probably wrong) is that contains table info and configuration for the database. So, I was wondering if the build process happens in a pipeline agent how it is possible for the local file to get updated. While typing this Im think that his info should be part of the .dacpac file

For a sample of the sql project, you may refer to the files under the path sql  in this sample

I saw the .sqlproj file (contains references to tables and sp) in your example and wondering: if this file exists locally (as part of the codebase) and you update some of your .sql files, to create new tables for instance, how this info is reflected in the .sqlproj if you only build it in the pipeline using MSBuild.

Or in other words how the .sqlproj file gets updated in case of updating the schema?

Hi @Potis23, Per your follow-up queries, I am sorry to say that I cannot answer them from the perspective of Azure DevOps, since I am not so familiar with SQL db project as Azure DevOps. The questions are more relevant to the SQL db project than Azure DevOps. For this, I would suggest you post those specific queries on SQL database project in a new thread. Regarding the findings in our current post, I will share a sample in the answer shortly.

Based on the discussions, the .sln or .sqlproj files from your SQL database project should NOT be considered as artifacts but ought to be pushed as source code into one of your cloud Azure Repos, so that they could be built by the VSBuild@1 pipeline task running in an agent job.
Taking the SQL database project for example, the pipeline can either build WideWorldImportersDW.sln or WideWorldImportersDW.sqlproj to generate the .dacpac package and then deploy it to Azure SQL database via the SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 pipeline task. Here is a sample YAML pipeline for your reference.
variables:
  ARMSvcCnnName: YourAzureResourceManagerServiceConnectionName
  AzureSQLServerName: YourAzureSQLSeverName
  AzureSQLDBName: YourAzureSQLDBName
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build DACPAC from SQL Database Project'
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sqlproj'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure SQL DB'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnnName)'
    AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
    ServerName: '$(AzureSQLServerName).database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: '$(AzureSQLDBName)'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
    DacpacFile: '**\*.dacpac'
    AdditionalArguments: '/v:ETLUserPassword="$(sql-password)" /v:AppUserPassword="$(sql-password)"'
    IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
    DeleteFirewallRule: false






Thanks Alvin!! Super much appreciated!!

Hi @Potis23, Anytime and glad to know my sample workflow may help.

Thank you again for your insights and sharing. Cheers!

I ll probably accept it as the answer nut let me take some time to test it out first. I m still trying to figure out how the .sqlproj file gets updated in case of schema changes in any of the .sql files

Sure. And the Azure SQL server and db deployment can be different case by case, which may result in different deployment failures in pipeline runs. We can sort out the correct deployment method/configuration based on the error messages. In all cases, please feel welcome to reach out to us. Always willing to help.
